# Optimal assignment for an unsatisfiable formula

Tags: logic, algorithms, propositional-calculus, satisfiability, conjunctive-normal-form

Given an unsatisfiable formula $F$ in CNF, are there any methods to find an assignment that can satisfy as many clauses as possible?

Comment: Are you sure this is _predicate_ logic? "CNF" is usually used about _propositional_ formulas.

Comment: Isn't this the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_satisfiability_problem ?

Comment: Related question in StackOverflow: [Algorithm to detect and remove least number of inconsistent facts (probably in PROLOG)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25828549/algorithm-to-detect-and-remove-least-number-of-inconsistent-facts-probably-in-p)

Comment: Yes, there are methods - brute force search is one. No, there are no polynomial time methods - the problem is NP hard.  Could you please clarify the question to indicate what sort of methods you are looking for?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo: your comment answers this question, I believe. Why don't you upgrade it to an answer?

Comment: @RobArthan Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the [maximum satisfiability problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_satisfiability_problem) (MAX-SAT):

[image]

Source:

- A. Biere, M. Heule, H. van Maaren, [Handbook of Satisfiability](https://books.google.com/books?id=shLvAgAAQBAJ), IOS Press, 2009.